# Ionic 4 tabs navigation pulls content to bottom

Tags: angular6, angular-routing, ionic4

I'm developping an Hybrid App with IONIC 4.
The first page is a login (left) the second the home once authenticated (right):

[image]

As you can see the content for each tab is hidden on the bottom and only the component header is shown.

Here is some code:

Home routes

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'newsfeed',
                outlet: 'newsfeed',
                loadChildren: '../news-feed/news-feed.module#NewsFeedPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'sitters',
                outlet: 'sitters',
                loadChildren: '../sitters/sitters.module#SittersPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'userprofile',
                outlet: 'userprofile',
                loadChildren: '../user-profile/user-profile.module#UserProfilePageModule'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home/tabs/(newsfeed:newsfeed)'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomePageRoutingModule { }
```

Homepage router outlet and tabs

```
<ion-tabs color="warning" useRouter="true">
  <ion-tab label="Feed" icon="paw" href="/home/tabs/(newsfeed:newsfeed)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="newsfeed"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Sitters" icon="people" href="/home/tabs/(sitters:sitters)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="sitters"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Profile" icon="person" href="/home/tabs/(userprofile:userprofile)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="userprofile"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Each tab component has somethig like

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>news-feed</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <p>Hello there.</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

But the content is always on the bottom. Any ideas? Thanks in advance warriors

Comment: This is because of lazy loading. Fyi: with [4.0.0-beta.18](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta18-2018-12-13) the usage of ion-tab was removed and it's not necessary to use named outlets. Current **Demo** + **Explanation** can be found [here](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing).

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter the same issue. And i spent almost 4 days trying to figure it out !
This is because of lazy loading. So you must do that :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import NewsfeedPage from '../news-feed/news-feed.page';
import SittersPage from '../sitters/sitters.page';
import UserProfilePage from '../user-profile/user-profile.page';


import { HomePage } from './home.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'newsfeed',
                outlet: 'newsfeed',
                component: NewsFeedPage
            },
            {
                path: 'sitters',
                outlet: 'sitters',
                component: SittersPage
            },
            {
                path: 'userprofile',
                outlet: 'userprofile',
                loadChildren: UserProfilePage
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home/tabs/(newsfeed:newsfeed)'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomePageRoutingModule { }
```

**Don't forget to import the modules in your home.module.ts**

Hope it will help.